# MATLAB lsqlin error: Number of iterations exceeded options.MaxIter

Tags: optimization, matlab

I define a `C` and `d` matrices, then call `lsqlin`:

```
lb = zeros(2, 1);
x = lsqlin(C, d, [], [], [], [], lb, []);
```

I get a solution for `x`, but a message that:

> Maximum number of iterations exceeded; increase `OPTIONS.MaxIter`.

The [function page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) says this is not the same as converging on a solution. But I don't know how to increase `OPTIONS.MaxIter`, or what is causing the warning. Any advice would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MaxIter` is an option you can include in your function call. This is a quote from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html):

```
x = lsqlin(C,d,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,x0,options)
```

And "`options`" can be used to increase `MaxIter` beyond it's default value of `200`. This, however, has to be done using [`optimoptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html):

```
options = optimoptions('lsqlin','MaxIter',1500)
```

or

```
options = optimoptions(@lsqlin,'MaxIter',1500)
```

Or, you can try using the [`optimtool` GUI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimtool.html). If you don't want to run your problem from the GUI, export the `options` variable to your workspace and declare it as `global`.

Comment: Thanks! I used the GUI, exported the options variable to the workspace, and declared it as global.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of matlab, you need to look at the `optimset` function to achieve this. `optimoptions` is a new function that may not be available to you.

It has a similar syntax:

```
options = optimset('MaxIter',1500)
```

You can read more about setting options [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/set-options.html)

Comment: If I had read more carefully, though, I would have noticed that it specifies that with the toolbox this function will indeed work for other functions. I'll delete my comment